# How to make an element appear then disappear on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, onclick

I have been trying to make a random image appear on click by adding a fadeOut effect and then removing the class. when I click it works fine, but I don't know how to remove the class after a few milliseconds and then being able to appear again on another click. so far I have just been able to make it fade out on click, I have tried a setInterval function so that the class gets removed after 1 millisecond but didn't work so I erased it, but even then, I don't know how to make the .on('click', function()) function fire on every click, instead of just working once. any help or tips would be really appreciated. Thanks!

```
<style>
body {
  background-color: black;
}

img {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 40px;
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 3em;
}

</style>    

<img class="red" 
src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/f/1/f/130267960774173786paint- 
splash(red)-md.png" alt="">

<img class="blue" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Q/3/H/u/Z/K/dark-blue- 
splash-ink-hi.png" alt="">

<img class="yellow" src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/y/m/m/p/P/yellow- 
splash-ink-md.png" alt="">

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 var red = $(".red");
 var blue = $(".blue");
 var yellow = $(".yellow");
 var images = [red, blue, yellow];

 $(document).on('click', function(){
 $(images[(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))]).addClass("animated fadeOut");
 });
})
//i should be able to click anywhere on the screen and a random image should appear and then fadeout each time there is a click
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```js
$(document).on("click", function() {
  $("#element").show(0, function() {
    $("#element").fadeOut();
  });
});
$("#element").hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="element">Element</span>
```

Comment: sorry but this is not what i was looking for, i want to be able to click anywhere on the screen and the image should appear and fade out immediately. this should happen instantly every time i click, sorry if i didn't make that clear.

Comment: @Acorn: Then it is even easier. Take a look at the edit.

Comment: BRO, THANK YOU SO MUCH, code ended up being like this,                                   $(document).on("click", function() {
  $(images[(Math.floor(Math.random()*3))]).show(0, function() {
    $(this).fadeOut();
  });
});

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using jQuery so you simply need to:

1) Create a function that hides the class.  Example:

```
function hideStuff(){
  $(".myimg").hide();
}
```

2) Add a class to your image files so they have a common selector (like "myimg" below).  You may also want to add an "alt" attribute (was missing in your code).  Example:

```
<img class="yellow myimg" src="http://www.clker.com/stuff" alt="image-three">
```

3) Add the timeout as part of your function with the amount of delay you want.  While it is not required, you should include a variable name so you can call it in the future.  Example:

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout( hideStuff, 5000);
```

Hopefully these will get you going in the right direction.

Comment: thank you, but this still doesn't solve the problem that every image only appears once. i want to make them appear each time i click.

Comment: The code above is used to make them hide() after a set time.  You need to add $(".myimg").show();  to an event listener with on click that will trigger the image to show.

Comment: yes, i realised on acorns code, this it the finished version https://codepen.io/insignia673/pen/GdrrRZ

Answer (score 0):

Both `.fadeOut()` and `.hide()` set `display: none`, which could effect your layout. I think you're looking to animate opacity to 0, and then in the callback function you can change the image source. I'd recommend using a div and setting the `background-image` property since divs are a bit more layout friendly. Also, you could either use classes and set the `background-image` property in the `<style>` section or you can make an array of the image urls and randomly pick from that (which is what I did here).

```
let images = [
'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/0/f/1/f/130267960774173786paint-splash(red)-md.png',
'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/Q/3/H/u/Z/K/dark-blue-splash-ink-hi.png',
'http://www.clker.com/cliparts/3/y/m/m/p/P/yellow-splash-ink-md.png'
];

$(document).on('click', function() {
  let $img = $('.img'); //so you don't have to make a new object everytime it's used

  if ($img.css('opacity') === '1') {
    $img.animate({ opacity: 0 }, function() { 
      $img.css('background-image', `url(${images[Math.floor(Math.random()*3)]})`); 
    });    
  } else {
    $img.animate({ opacity: 1 });
  }
}).click().click(); //two clicks to initialize image
```

https://jsfiddle.net/yc4e4nxb/3/

NOTE: JSfiddle doesn't seem to like wherever these images are hosted, so it's working kind of erratically. Hopefully you get the gist of what this code is doing though.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correct, In [This Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sijanbhattarai/62rxrc5g/) the button element disappears when you click anywhere in the screen and then re appears immediately. Hope this will work.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $(document).on('click',function(){
         $("#myElement").fadeOut().delay(100).fadeIn();
       });
   });
```